# How to multiply numbers separated by dashes '-' with another number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to multiply numbers separated by dashes with another number. How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

I tried using strip but the code gets complex.

For Example:

```
a = '1-2,3-4,4-5'
b = '3.0'
```

So if you take variable 'a' first value i.e, '1-2', the number after '-' dash should be multiplied by 'b' variable value and the result should be like 1-2*3.0 = 1-6.0

My result should look like:

```
res = '1-6.0,3-12.0,4-15.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` is your friend here. First, you'll need to split your string into pairs:

```
pairs = a.split(',')
```

Now, you'll have `['1-2', '3-4', '4-5']`.

Now go ahead and split those pairs:

```
for pair in pairs:
    x, y = pair.split('-')
```

Now, `y` will still be a string, so before you can multiple, you'll need to parse it to an int with int(y). Since `b` is a string, you'll also need `float(b)` (or just start with `b = 3.0` in the first place.

So you can add that to the look above

```
for pair in pairs:
    x, y = pair.split('-')
    y = int(y)
```

Ok, so now you'll need to store the results. Create a empty list before the loop to store the new pairs:

```
multiplied_pairs = []
for pair in pairs:
    x, y = pair.split('-')
    y = int(y)
    multiplied_pairs.append('{}-{}'.format(x, y * float(b)))
```

Finally, use `join` to re-create the new string, with the results:

```
print(','.join(multiplied_pairs))
```

Put it all together and you'll have:

```
pairs = a.split(',')
multiplied_pairs = []

for pair in pairs:
    x, y = pair.split('-')
    y = int(y)
    multiplied_pairs.append('{}-{}'.format(x, y * float(b)))

print(','.join(multiplied_pairs))
```

Now for the bonus round, if you want to do it all at once with some generator expressions:

```
print(','.join(
    '{}-{}'.format(x, int(y) * float(b)) 
    for x, y in (
        pair.split('-') for pair in a.split(',')
    )
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string, do the arithmetics with the items, and then the join the items back:

```
','.join('%s-%.1f' % (i, float(b) * int(n)) for p in a.split(',') for i, n in (p.split('-'),))
```

This returns:

```
1-6.0,3-12.0,4-15.0
```